# Как обрезать текст только после двух первых строк?

Tags: html, css

Как обрезать текст только после двух первых строк, при этом ширина блока содержащего текст растягивается в зависимости от размера экрана. И если первые две строки не умещаются по высоте то блок растягивается также и по высоте пока полностью не уместит эти 2 строки. Как такое реализовать?

Подобное реализовано на сайте https://www.fl.ru/projects/?kind=4

[image: Вот размер экрана большой]

[image: А вот по меньше что соответсвует размеру экрана телефона]

Comment: Я вижу, что при уменьшении ширины там точно не 2 строки получается.

Answer (score 4):

Вот мой пример:
https://jsfiddle.net/g0h10ede/1/

Что важно -

```
.field {
  width: 500px;
  height: calc(25px * 3); /* не стал писать 75px, чтобы показать, что максимум по высоте на 3 строки выделяю блок */

  padding: 5px;

  border: 1px solid black;

    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 25px; /* каждая строка будет по высоте 25px, чтобы я точно мог установить высоту блока (это чисто визуально, ни на что не влияет) */
  text-align: justify;

    /* а вот это как раз и дает результат "..." в многострочном тексте */
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

**P.S.**

Если ты хочешь иметь однострочный текст, который заканчивается "...", то надо сделать так:
https://jsfiddle.net/g0h10ede/

```
.field {
  width: 500px;

  padding: 5px;

  border: 1px solid black;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  line-height: 25px; 
  text-align: justify;
}
```

**P.P.S.**

залез на исходник приведённого тобой сайта и там не увидел вообще каких-то свойств css, направленных на обрезание текста - скорее всего он режется на уровне скриптов (например, с использованием javascript) или на сервере

Comment: Всегда интересовало - если ставят '-1' значит, ответ чем-то не понравился и на будущее хотелось бы узнать - чем. Человек, не стесняйся, напиши :)

Answer (score 0):

Предыдущий вариант работает только в вебките.

Вот универсальная библиотека:
https://dollarshaveclub.github.io/shave/